# how to edit py file in azure repo using azure devops pipline?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have lots of py files in repo and I want to edit them using azure devops pipline, is that possible?
every time I put a file I can edit it with CI / CD

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your goal?

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> how to edit py file in azure repo using azure devops pipline?

You could use the REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=6.0
```

Update a file, Request Body:

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "fd1062428e0567cfbfcc28ac59d4bea077ce81c1"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added a few more items to the task list.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2\n* Item 3\n* Item 4\n\nIf you need to add more, update this file and add them!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the `oldobjectid` is the **latest commit ID** on the current branch for the Azure Devops Repo.

To get the `oldObjectId` (latest commit id), we could use the REST API [Pushes - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with URI Parameters `top=1` and `searchCriteria.refName=refs/heads/master`:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?&$top=1&searchCriteria.refName=refs/heads/master&api-version=6.0
```

[image]

Now, we get the `pushId`, and we could use the REST API [Pushes - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the `commitId`:

[image]

Then, we could use the REST API Pushes - Create with request body:

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "e71544e80870e83cfd3eb3a797eda9c6227c66a7"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added task markdown file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The test result:

[image]